# How to adjust the product price to get accurate profit in Point of Sale

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing issue to manage the product prices to get the accurate profit.

Currently I'm calculating the profit as.

```
Profit = (quantity*productSalePrice)-(quantity*productBuyPrice)
```

But let suppose price of the product is updated after two month. So when I will get the history of the last month then the profit will be calculated based on the new price, so it will not be accurate profit.

Let suppose there are total 15 stock of the product and 5 of them having the old price and next 10 have the latest price, how I can calculate the profit on this?

Comment: in my website db when I associate the product with the order, in the pivot table, i save the quantity and also the selling price (same thing happens for example if you have discounts, when they expired, you have to maintain the old price to display it to the user)

Comment: How you maintain the old price of the product? Let suppose there are total 15 stock of the product and 5 of them having the old price and next 10 have the latest price, how I can calculate the profit on this?

Comment: i mean, why your product should have 2 different prices at the same time? you have in your table products, the actual price, and in the pivot the selling price, so if you have to sell something, you use the current price in the product table, if you have to calculate the profit, you use the price in the pivot

Comment: @Berto99 you are not getting my point. i understand we can store the product price with the order, but let suppose I got new stock with different price and some existing stock with old price, how to manage that? So the old stock should be sold on the old price, instead of new.

Comment: ok, well, i can't se how this relates to the original question, but i may suggest you maybe to duplicate the product, or make a new table called "variants" with product id, price, quantity, and then associate the order with those variants, and not to the product

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to stock products with different purchase prices & expiration date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373292/what-is-the-best-way-to-stock-products-with-different-purchase-prices-expirati)